# Understanding lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I read about delegates and lambda expressions, but this code is still magic for me.

```
    OnFailure FailureCallback(string failedFunction){
        return failureResponse => Console.Error.WriteLine("Failed to " + failedFunction + " due to: " + failureResponse.Message);
    }
```

Where *OnFailure* is delegate with signature:

```
public delegate void OnFailure(FailureResponse failureResponse);
```

And *FailureResponse* is class that preforms actions with failure response.

What makes "failureResponse" appear from nowhere at callback? This is not parameter and is not declared anywhere, but yet it's used as a parameter for lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the declaration of a parameter for the lambda expression. It's the same as `x` in the following: `someSequence.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty)`.

Comment: Oh, and that's it? Declaration delegate's first parameter and then using it for lambda expression?

Comment: That is it, yes. It just looks so unusual in this particular syntax. As an exercise you could use R# to convert the lambda to a local variable. That will make it very obvious what is going on. The method is misnamed, btw. It should be called `GetFailureCallback`. Maybe that added to the confusion.